# 2002 Honda Civic coolant coming out of coolant reservoir after shut engine off

Tags: honda, civic, coolant

The car does not overheat and is fine when it is on. Once the car is shut off, sometimes (50/50) coolant will escape from the reservoir cap, it is hot, it looks clean. What could this be? We just changed the rad cap and that didnt fix it. About enough coolant to fill a shot glass or 2 spills out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What type of coolant do you use? If you don't know *exactly*, tell me what the color is.

Comment: Is the reservoir overfilled?  In most cases there is an "L" line and an "H" line to indicate where the level should be between.  If you have filled the tank to the top, then leaking out is expected.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I dont know what the last owner put in, but i have topper it up with prestone 50/50 pre-diluted (the yellow bottle). I think the color before i topped up was sort of bright yellow maybe green ish (sorry working from memory)

Comment: @jwh20 The first time it happened I am not sure what level the coolant was at. But the second time, I drove the car for 45 mins and shut it off and nothing happened, then the next day, I drove it for another 45 mins and it happened again. (the coolant was right on the H line when it was cold).

Comment: Generally the level should be at the "L" or "COLD" line when cold.  I think your reservoir is overfilled.

Comment: @jwh20 I just checked 2 separate videos of 1Aauto and carcarekiosk that show how to top up coolant for my car and they say top up the the full line when cold. This is what I did. Also it is odd that it did not spill out sometimes, it appears to bit a bit random.

Comment: @jimlayhey - The reason why I asked is, the D17A engines (which you have one in your car) are known to get blown head gaskets if you run anything other than the Honda blue type (doesn't have to be specifically Honda coolant, but *made for Honda*). The "green" stuff eats the head gasket away and causes a leak. I wouldn't doubt at this point you have this issue.